# How to access a controller assigned through routeProvider outside of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a jquery/flash based microphone recording plugin and I want to be able to call a function inside an Angular controller to process the audio further.

Inside an ng-view I load a template and assign the controller I want to access via a routeProvider. In this template I have a top div element. I thought I could access the controller by doing:

```
e = document.getElementById("topElement");
scope = angular.element(e).scope();
```

And then in de microphone callback call:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.functionInController(micData);
});
```

But scope.functionInController is not defined.
By inspecting the scope element I can see that functionInController actually lives inside the $$childHead of the scope I retrieve, but I cannot seem to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your callback to:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.$$childHead.functionInController(micData);
});
```

Comment: You're right, thanks! Keep forgetting to call $apply outside of angular all the time :)